# How to plot functions with large slope on a compact domain?

Tags: plotting

The Mathematica command
    `Plot[(1 - r^2)^(1/32), {r, -1, 1}]`
does not plot the function near the boundary points. That is, the graph does not attain 0 at r = +-1. Increasing `WorkingPrecision` and `PlotPoints` does not seem to help. How does one fix the graph to match the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use `ListLinePlot`:

```
ListLinePlot@Table[{r, (1 - r^2)^(1/32)}, {r, -1, 1, 1/100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Plot` uses open sampling to avoid singularities at endpoints:

```
Cases[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], Line[p_] :> First@p, Infinity]
Cases[Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], Line[p_] :> First@p, Infinity]
(* both yield  {{2.04082*10^-8, 4.16493*10^-16}}  *)
```

---

**Alternative**

`ParametricPlot` does not seem to use open sampling, although it seems to choose a plot range based on the density of plotted points, excluding the two endpoints with default `PlotRange`:

```
ParametricPlot[{r, (1 - r^2)^(1/32)}, {r, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's a way out, I agree, but suddenly I find myself wondering, why `Plot` outright refuses to sample the endpoints.

Comment: Great solution, great explanation. Thanks! It would be nice to explore LLlAMnYP's train of thought as a collection of these curves is the output. This makes for a larger pdf file.

Comment: @dantopa 1) Thanks.  It used to be that `Plot` sampled the end points and complained bitterly about undefined functions etc.  I think user complaints led WRI to change the default behavior to make it easier to plot `Log`, `Tan`, `1/x` etc.  2) See alternative. 3) You might want to wait a day before accepting (thanks, though!) since there may be better answers; not having a accepted answer might encourage others to try out their ideas.

Comment: @Michael E2  `ParametricPlot` is the ideal solution. (It reinforces your point about waiting for a better solution.) Also, thanks for the introduction to `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: Nice job on six Accepts yesterday. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks.  A combination of being in the line-up and liking the pitches.