# How to add points on the empirical distribution function on the leftside of the pieces (steps)?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

Faced the problem.
Here is code:

```
data = Sort[
Sin[(b - a)*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n] + a]];
ScriptCapitalD = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
Plot[CDF[ScriptCapitalD, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Orange, ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed}]
```

And it plots this:
[image]

How can i add points on the leftside of each peace of it?
Here is example of what i want:[image]

Could you please help me? Thanks. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could add point to each line segment after the plot is generated:

```
SeedRandom[4];
data = Sort[Sin[2*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 12] + 0]];
ScriptCapitalD = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
Plot[CDF[ScriptCapitalD, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> None, Frame -> True] /. 
 Line[p_] :> {PointSize[0.015], Point[First@p], Line[p]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but look: http://i.imgur.com/D12kb8n.png
Is it bug or i have to fix it? I mean, it should go up to point (1, 1).

Comment: And one more question: how can i add horizontal lines [y = 0, {x, -Inf, 0}] and [y = 1, {x, 1, +Inf}]?

Comment: @instajke The same issue came up here earlier today: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83375  - The simplest fix is to make the plot domain `{x, 0, 1.001}` and perhaps set `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: @Micahel E2, i meant this: http://i.imgur.com/5G78tqt.png

Comment: @instajke Like this?: `Show[Plot[CDF[ScriptCapitalD, x], {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Orange, ExclusionsStyle -> None, Frame -> True] /. Line[p_] :> {PointSize[0.015], Point[First@p], Line[p]}, PlotRange -> {{-0.02, 1.02}, All}]` -- Plot more than you need and then chop it off with `Show` using a restricted `PlotRange`.  It gets rid of the dot at the origin, which I assumed you wanted.

Comment: one more question :3 How to add point on the right side of the line? Thanks.

Comment: @instajke Add `Point[Last@p]` to the list after `Point[First@p]`.

Comment: found problem: http://i.imgur.com/GBRizWl.png
Could You tell me, how to fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: @instajke Not without the complete code.  Either a point got dropped somehow or the base `Plot` is at fault.

Answer (score 6):

```
SeedRandom[123]
n = 15; a = 0; b = 2;
data = Sort[Sin[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{a, b}], n]]];
```

Yo can also specify the `PlotStyle` setting to add `Point` primitives to `Line`s:

```
Plot[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], y], {y, 0, 1}, Filling -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> ({Orange, Thick, #, PointSize[.0125], 
     Point[#[[1]]] & @@ #} &), ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use, perhaps more transparently,  `PlotStyle -> ({Orange, Thick, #, 
    PointSize[.0125], # /. Line -> Composition[Point, First]} &)`.

Alternatively,

```
Plot[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], y], {y, 0, 1}, Filling -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> ({Orange, Thick, #, PointSize[.0125], 
     Point[#[[1]]] & @@ #, PointSize[.005], White, 
     Point[#[[1]]] & @@ #} &), ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8225/125), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8644/125), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14607/125), [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77309/125), and [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48879/125) for additional examples.

Comment: That is great. I've often wanted `PlotStyle` to accept a function, but have never seen it in the docs.  That should be better known.  Is there a guide to usage somewhere?  Does it work on 3D plots? (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2, it is not in docs. My discovery of it was a pure accident  -- wishful thinking  ("wouldn't  it be great if something worked this way")  -> try a few cases -> pleasantly surprised that in some cases it does work:)  It does not work in all cases one would wish it to work. It appeared in several posts on this site over the last few years (I think the earliest is in an answer by Simon Woods or rcollyer) . I will dig up the links and add to the post.

Comment: Maybe it could be added here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/

Comment: @MichaelE2, I put the relevant  links I could find there.