# Encapsulated plot function misbehaves

Tags: plotting, functions

To insure a collection of plots has identical appearance, the plot command is encapsulated in a function. The results are undesirable. The fiducial plot is

```
 ggood = ParametricPlot[{r, ZernikeR[100, 0, r]}, {r, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, 1.05 {-1, 1}}]
```

which creates [image: plot of Zernike polynomial]

The functional version is

```
Clear[pp];
pp[ψ_, options___] := 
 ParametricPlot[{r, ψ}, {r, -1, 1}, options, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, 1.05 {-1, 1}}]

 gbad = pp[ZernikeR[100, 0, r]]
```

which produces

[image: bad plot]

How should the functional form be posed?

Comment: BTW: did you know that `ParametricPlot[{r, f[r]}, {r, a, b}]` is the same as `Plot[f[r], {r, a, b}]`? With the `HoldFirst` attribute you learned from the Wizard, you can now use this much simpler construction.

Comment: Michael E2 demonstrates the difference between these macros here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83375/how-to-plot-functions-with-large-slope-on-a-compact-domain. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MarcoB posted before me this has to do with evaluation differences.  Simply setting [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) on `pp` produces the original plot:

```
SetAttributes[pp, HoldFirst]

pp[ψ_, options___] := 
 ParametricPlot[{r, ψ}, {r, -1, 1}, options, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 1.05 {-1, 1}}]

pp[ZernikeR[100, 0, r]]
```

[image]

You will want this attribute anyway as without it the global value of `r` will be used, if it exists, which would result in even worse behavior.

As to why the symbolic expansion of `ZernikeR[100, 0, r]` needs extra [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) to get the desired output please see:

- [Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121)

Comment: `HoldFirst`! That's what I was looking for!! Man, I have spent the last ten minutes thinking "If only there was a way to tell a function not to evaluate its arguments..." Thank you for putting me out of my misery. I'm also out of votes, I've just realized, so I guess we owe each other one :-)

Comment: @MarcoB There is a whole family of Hold functions, e.g. `HoldRest`, `SequenceHold`, etc.  Some of the lesser known (I think) are `NHoldAll` (and rest, first) but these can be very important at times.

Comment: I definitely need to get some practice with those. I came across `HoldAll` and its effects early in my tinkering days, through the classical beginner's problem of coloring when plotting things that evaluate to lists, but are not lists yet. I should have followed through then! Anyway, I saw your post today re: [Robby Villegas tutorial on Unevaluated](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/), so I have it on my list of things to read. I've scanned it briefly, and I think it mentions `Hold*` attributes too.

Comment: @MrW: Great explanation and extremely helpful link! This solves many problems dealing with the Zernike polynomial set.

Answer (score 6):

This is a comment rather than an answer, but it grew too long for the comment box, and I wanted to show graphics, so I'll leave it here in hopes that someone better versed in the inner workings of MMA might explain this behavior. I am using your definition of the wrapper function `pp`.

First of all, I get a **slightly different version** of the "wrong" function:

[image: wrapped parametric plot]

Having said that, it seems that this behavior has something to do with the **order of evaluation**. In fact, if I pass the function to plot to the `pp` wrapper *unevaluated*, then I obtain the same well-behaved output as your "free standing" `ParametricPlot`:

```
pp[Unevaluated@ZernikeR[100, 0, r]]
```

[image: passing unevaluated]

The opposite is also true: if I pre-evaluate the `ZernikeR` function, then try to plot the result, I obtain the same result I had from feeding this function straight to your wrapper:

```
ZernikeR[100, 0, r];
ParametricPlot[{r, %}, {r, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 1.05 {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am afraid that this is as far as I was able to go to understand the problem. Depending on how you are constructing the lists of functions to plot, you may be able to **pass the functions unevaluated programmatically**, and get around the road block for now. For instance

```
pp /@ 
  Unevaluated/@ 
    Unevaluated@
      {ZernikeR[20, 0, r], ZernikeR[50, 0, r], ZernikeR[100, 0, r]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd still like to understand why this is the case, however.

Comment: +1 good observation.  If you see the polynomial that results from `ZernikeR[100, 0, r]` you can see why extended precision is needed.  Actually you can see the trouble if you just do `(z = ZernikeR[100, 0, r]; z /. r -> .9)`    vs `ZernikeR[100, 0, .9]`

Comment: @george2079 That's a very nice example, thank you. In fact, playing around with the precision of that $0.9$ shows that one needs at least 40 digits of precision to obtain a reasonable result... Ouch!

Comment: @MarcoB: Very nice approach; wonderful example.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the options and impose a reasonable `WorkingPrecision`:

```
Clear[pp];
pp[\[Psi]_] := 
 ParametricPlot[{r, \[Psi]}, {r, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, 1.05 {-1, 1}},
  WorkingPrecision -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `WorkingPrecision` only needed inside of the function wrapper? (Also, `WorkingPrecision->100` can be placed in the options slot.) One reason to use  `ParametricPlot` in lieu of `Plot` is to obviate the need to adjust `WorkingPrecision`. Thanks for your comment.